# how to limit to one option between two - argparse - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to limit the arguments on my command line to either -d or -f. How can I achieve that?

I could easily do it with `if` statements however I want to do it the correct way.

```
   subparser_post = subparsers.add_parser('post', add_help=False)
    subparser_post.add_argument("-d", '--d')
    subparser_post.add_argument("-f", "--f")
```

Comment: `if` tests after parsing are not wrong.  For this simple case the `mutually exclusive group` feature works, but for more complex cases you may need to use the post-parsing tests.  That question has come up often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a mutually-exclusive group.

```
subparser_post = subparsers.add_parser('post', add_help=False)
group = subparser_post.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-d", '--d')
group.add_argument("-f", "--f")
```

Add `required=True` to the call to `add_mutually_exclusive_group` if the user must use one of the two options.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a mutually exclusive group:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')

print parser.parse_args()
```

This creates a way to only allow a or b, not both.